# Prompting a user whether java web start application is running or not?

Tags: java, web, browser, java-web-start

I need to display a prompt to a user who is using a web application depending on whether a java web start application named javaws.exe(The name which appears in the Taks manager on running the application) is running or not on his machine , How do i achieve this ? Thnx In Advance .

Comment: You've obviously learned *nothing* from my answer to the duplicate question. I don't know why you bother asking.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers can't do things like checking which applications are installed.

There used to be a way to check using Javascript and ActiveX in Internet Explorer:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/launch.html#ie

But that link is quite old, only works in IE, and probably needs special Internet Settings in order to work now.

You might be better off trying to launch a "test" WebStart application from a browser page.  Then you can add some instructions to your page to say how to install WebStart "if the application doesn't launch properly".  Instructions for launching here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html#web